# Messenger group videochat not working

Tags: video

I use ubuntu 19.10, and i tried in facebook messenger to access the group videochat with firefox vainly, the recommandec chromium neither works. Thanks for help.

Comment: You may want to describe more about what you meant by "not works".

Comment: Chromium frost the computer, when i'm trying to access the group video chat through chromium, this attempt block the whole system.